# How to combine priors for empirical bayes

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, empirical-bayes

I am trying to estimate $Z_{i} = P(Y=1 | A=a_{i}, B = b_{i}, C =c_{i})$ using something like empirical Bayes as in http://varianceexplained.org/r/empirical_bayes_baseball/

aggregating a massive amount of data and not being able to apply a complex model due to the data size (there are thousands of levels of A, B and C). Y is binary. Although I have lots of data, not all possible combinations of A, B and C will be present or may have low frequency in the data. The definition of each Z is the combination of the A, B and C's. Something like "what is the probability of a positive event for A = 'red' and B = 'small' and C = 'round'.

While the data is sparse in cases, there is a lot of A, B and C individually. Empirical Bayes seemed like a good choice but how would I combine the priors. For example if I am calculating $P(Y=1 | A=1, B = 0, C =150)$ where 1, 0 and 150 are just string indexes of categories.

I can compute $P(Y=1 |  A=1, B = 0, C =150)$
as
$P(Y=1 |  A=1, B = 0, C =150) / [(P(Y=1 |  A=1, B = 0, C =150)+P(Y=0 |  A=1, B = 0, C =150))]$

and I can compute things such as $P(Y=1 |  A=1) / [(P(Y=1 |  A=1)+P(Y=0 |  A=1))]$ and other subsets. How can I combine these subsets (priors) into the numerator and denominator for $P(Y=1 |  A=1, B = 0, C =150)$?

Comment: If you're just trying to estimate the proportion of True for each $Z_i$ using empirical bayes, treat each $Z_i$ like an individual baseball player and follow the procedure in the linked article. Each  $Z_i$ will have some observed proportion of True (eg. 11/68). Fit a Beta to the distribution of proportions and that is your prior. Calculate posterior for each $Z_i$. Does that capture what you are trying to do?

Comment: I dont want to use as the prior all other Zs (all baseball players). A baseball player here is comprised of attributes we have data for (e.g. height, weight, handedness). Some of the combinations we want predictions for are new without any exact history or examples (pretend we see new types of handedness in the prediction set). I want to compute the prior built up from prior information we do have...

Comment: That makes sense. Perhaps the naive bayes algorithm is what you are looking for?

Comment: except NB will return zero for any new categories (e.g. the new handedness)

Comment: I don't seem to understand your original question. But this thread speaks to the issue of unseen categories in naive bayes https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108618/how-to-handle-unseen-features-in-a-naive-bayes-classifier